# Load images in order, with delay, fallback for no script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if anyone has a nice clean solution to loading images from top to bottom of a page, waiting for the previous image to load before going to the next. And in case the user dosent have javascript fall back on a regular `<img>` tag.

There are quite a few lazy loading plugins, but I would like to load all images as fast as possible in the order they appear on the website.

The reason for this is that each image is rather large, and the user will look through them from top to bottom in a rather slow fashion.

Comment: What's your issue? Have you tried something that doesn't work. Do you have a bug in your code? Do you have an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've been using lazy loading images plugins untill now, but its not doing what I want, and I couldent find anything on how to do the question I asked.

Comment: +1 for this fallback thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interesting question. my approach would be something like this

```js
$(function(){

  var loadNext = function(){
    var next_guy = $('#imgz img[x-src]').first();
    next_guy.prop('src', next_guy.attr('x-src'));
    next_guy.removeAttr('x-src');
    
  };
  
  $('#imgz img').on('load',loadNext);
  
});
```

```css
#imgz img {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgz">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/mThaO.jpg" />
  <img x-src="http://i.imgur.com/DO1kZ.jpg" />
  <img x-src="http://i.imgur.com/lD2HS.jpg" />
  <img x-src="http://i.imgur.com/4vqE3.jpg" />
  <img x-src="http://i.imgur.com/TXXbx.jpg" />
  <img x-src="http://i.imgur.com/TF3z2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Abdul's answer has elegance, because browsers do this anyway (try to load images in order), and the end user gets the benefit of prefetching. still, in order to more deterministically control this flow,

Comment: I beleive this is the only answer which actually delays the loading of each image untill the previous image is done, (changes the src tag in the element when previous image is done). Going to use a variant of your code, thank you.

Comment: it doesn't provide the graceful degradation you asked for, but it gets you halfway there.

Comment: added an image tag in <noscript> in the same place and put a display:none in the image tag above that i remove with JS for the degeneration. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this, first add this css

```
   img{display:none;}
```

jquery

```
   $("img").each(function(index, value){
   $(this).delay(300*index).fadeIn();   


   });
```

for fallback you can do this , add this jquery first that will run only if js enabled

```
$(function(){$('body').addClass('jse');});
```

then this

```
  $("img").each(function(index, value){
   $(this).delay(300*index).fadeIn();   


   });
```

and in css, that will onle be applied if jquery worded and body has class .jse

```
 .jse img {display:none;}
```

Comment: So if an image element i hidden, the image is not loaded?

Comment: loaded but it is hidden, you cant to lazy load (create one after other) or display them one after other?

Comment: it will be good to load them first keeping them hidden as they will take time for loading, and should just display them with delay

Comment: This won't show images if js is disabled as question states it should,

Comment: i have given fallback to it @ceath, check now mate

Comment: @jensB i got your point of fallback late, have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $images = $("img");
    //First hide all images
    $images.hide();

    function lazyLoad(num) {
        $images.eq(num).fadeIn(function () {
            if (num != $images.length) {
                lazyLoad(++num);
            }
        });
    }
    //When first has loaded start fading in
    $images.eq(0).load(function () {
        lazyLoad(0);
    });
});
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud6y36w4/2/)